# How to bound the header template of the datalist control to a data item?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datalist

I have the following stuff to bound the header template to a data item. but this not working.

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" 
            Text='<%# Eval("Title") %>' onclick="LinkButton1_Click" 
            Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Large" ForeColor="Black" CssClass="heading"></asp:LinkButton><br />
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("content1") %>' 
            Font-Size="Medium"  CssClass="content"></asp:Label><br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("content2") %>' 
             CssClass="content"></asp:Label><br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("content3") %>' 
             CssClass="content"></asp:Label><br />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

Please help me how to bound the controls in header template of a data list to a data item.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The `HeaderTemplate` is not affected by items in your DataSource, so you'll need to bind it to something else.

Try creating a public property in your class file:

```
public string Title
{
   get;
   set;
}
```

And bind your `HeaderTemplate` to it, without `Eval`:

```
<HeaderTemplate>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" onclick="LinkButton1_Click" 
        Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Large" ForeColor="Black" CssClass="heading">
        <% =Title %>
    </asp:LinkButton><br />
</HeaderTemplate>
```